# Are there techniques for quickly seeing patterns in numbers?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, mental-arithmetic

Recently I was watching 8 out of 10 cats does countdown (S18E01 - 26 July 2019), for which the math question there was the following numbers:

*if you haven't seen countdown, you are provided 6 numbers, in which can only use one number once, and can only use the operators; add, subtract, multiply and divide, in order to reach a particular number*.

The numbers were [25, 50, 10, 7, 7, 6], and the target was 931.

None of the contestants got the answer (Jon Richardson was close with 932). The host Jimmy Carr asked Rachel Riley if it could be done, to which she responded

> It wasn't easy, but I found three ways. Example, $25-6=19$, $7\times7=49$ and then multiply them together to get $19\times49=931$.

John Richardson then jokingly asked; "Did you do that on your 19 times table, or your 49 times table.".

Rachel replied with:

> $7 \times 133$, so $7 \times 7 \times 19$...

To which (in the spirit of comedy) was interrupted.

I'm going to guess the $133$ came from $6*25-10-7$, but I frequently see an ability shown by some people to quickly see combinations of numbers and quickly perform operations.

Are there techniques that one can learn in order to develop this ability, like alternative ways of interpreting numbers or more complex relationships between numbers? Or are some people just blessed with a mind that works that way?

Comment: Isn't it *obvious* that you'd try to obtain the prime decomposition of the target number (and perhaps some useful numbers nearby)?

Comment: parity arguments may help. if you were to make a sum of two terms you would need to have one of the terms odd, any product of terms must have all terms odd etc.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yesss, so _obvious_ I just had to search what prime decomposition is. And RoddyMacPhee I am aware of properties such as that, still doesn't help too much in my speed of finding patterns.

Comment: In this case having lots of practice is likely helpful, Rachel Riley has been doing these calculations on Countdown for about a decade, though I'm not sure how good she is now compared to when she started.

Comment: Yeah, maybe so. She seems just as good now as she did back then.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, one important item which is omitted from the question is that there's a 30 second time limit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor OK, then you better train *fast* prime decomposition.